# Visual studio code barra inferior azul

Tags: vscode

buenos dias a todos quisiera saber si hay una manera de cambiar de color o quitar esta barra inferior de visual studio code recién estoy migrando de sublime text y no estoy muy familiarizado con el editor por favor espero puedan ayudarme muchas gracias :)[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ve a *settings* (`Ctrl/Command + ,`) y edítalo como [json](/questions/tagged/json). A continuación, agrega las siguientes líneas:

[image]

Para mayor información acerca de la personalización de VSCode, consulta [este enlace](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color).

Comment: muchas gracias amigo.!

Comment: @JeysonRamos No olvides marcar la respuesta que consideres correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Si se puede ocultar. Cambiar de color creo que no.
Por cierto esta barra se llama `statusBar`.

Siguiendo estos pasos:

1. Entra en el menú de `settings`. La forma más rápida, icono inferior izquierdo(tuerca) y luego `Settings`. Si no, `File` --> `Preferences` --> `Settings`.
2. Arriba a la derecha en el símbolo de `{}`. Se te abrirá el archivo `settings.json`
3. Añade la siguiente linea.

   "workbench.statusBar.visible": false

La otra forma es des del menú de `settings`.

1. Entra en el menú de `settings`. La forma más rápida, icono inferior izquierdo(tuerca) y luego `Settings`.Si no, `File` --> `Preferences` --> `Settings`.
2. Abre el menu de `WorkBench`.
3. Abre el menú de `Appearance`.
4. Buscas donde dice `Status var: Visible` y desmarcas la casilla.

*Ambos caminos llevan a Roma, ya que el fichero `settings.json` es editado de la misma forma.*

Comment: muchas gracias amigo.!